How can amount of <select> elements be determined by other element?
I'm working on a project for school in Spring with Thymeleaf. Now it's about football games and editing the score and who scored.
 <form th:action="@{|/admin/editfuturegame/*{id}|}" method="post">
        <label for="homescore">Home team score</label>
        <input id="homescore" type="number" th:field="*{homeScore}">
        <label for="awayscore">Away team score</label>
        <input id="awayscore" type="number" th:field="*{awayScore}">
        <label for="scorer">Goalscorer</label>
        <select id="scorer" name="scorers" multiple>
            <option th:each="player: ${allGamePlayers}" th:value="${player.getId()}" th:text="${player.getName()}"></option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="save">
    </form>

Now I have this code to select who scored, but the problem is that I can't select someone two times of course. I was wondering if it's possible in some way that, depending on the homescore and the awayscore more select elements appear for each goal one?
I have been searching on the internet but it seems like it's only possible with JavaScript and I couldn't figure out yet how that should be done.

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to build but I'd say there's a conceptual flaw in your UI. Right now your UI seems to be about the final score of a game and the players who scored which is fine. If you need more details you might need to change your UI, e.g. provide a way to add players along with their individual score and then determine home and away team's score by the individual players' scores and which team they belong to.
